# Button links not redirecting prospect theme wordpress

Tags: button, hyperlink, shortcode

I recently installed prospect theme and i am having tons of trouble as most things aren't customizable directly from the options interface. You can see a demo here: 
http://themes.wpbusinessbundle.com/prospect/

So i'm trying to add buttons, which when i add them look fine, but don't redirect anywhere (redirects to the same page with #). I know it's because of something missing that needs to ''pull'' the link I include in the html when i write/insert the button but can't figure out where to modify it in the css or how.

Any help is appreciated. Btw, Calls to action work but I cannot change their color or their size so that's not much good.

Answer (score 1):

From observation of the PHP, the shortcode for a button should be arranged to match:

```
"extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'link'  => '#',
    'target'    => '',
    'variation' => '',
    'size'  => '',
    'align' ...."
```

What this means is the button shortcode that the visual editor makes will have to be manually edited to look something like this for example:

[button link="http://google.com" variation="blue"  size="large"] TEST [/button]

I'm using the theme myself and I've had to edit a lot of the.. questionable code ;P.

Hope this helps.